# Doxygen with classic ASP (VBscript)

Tags: asp-classic, documentation, doxygen

Is it possible to use Doxygen on classic-asp-files (written in VBscript)?

I found something called vbfilter.py, but I don't know how to use it. Can somebody please help me?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Finally, i could get it running.

requirements:
python 2.x

https://code.google.com/p/doxy-filter/source/browse/trunk/vbfilter.py?spec=svn1&r=1
download the vbfilter.py from Basti Grembowietz

in vbfilter.py modify def filter. you have to add a line for "asp".
then save the file in the root directory of the project

in Doxygen-settings, in the expert/input-area you have to set input_filter to vbfilter.py and the file_patterns to *.asp

(if you have python 3.x, there is another version, but take care. it's optimized for japanese usage. somewhere in that vbfilter.py codepage is set to CP932 and you have to set it to IS-8859-15 or whatever you need )

Answer (score 0):

Looks like you will have to ask the developer to add support for classic ASP. The "vbfilter.py" you found is Python, really not relevant as far as I can tell.

In the [official page](http://www.doxygen.nl/) he says:

> You can submit enhancement requests in [the bug tracker](https://github.com/doxygen/doxygen/issues/new).

Comment: Yes, the filter runs in python, but it should process visual-basic-files. Thanks for the Bugzilla-tipp. I think, a lot of people still have old visual-basic, vbscript or asp-applications running.

Comment: No problem, sorry I don't have better news. :/